# Communicate a change in one of children to parent's parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is how my "hierarchy" looks:

```
Game
    Table
        TableRow
            Cell
```

When a cell is clicked on, I want to run a method from Game. React's design is a bit different than what I'm used to and I just can't wrap my mind around communicating a change in Cell back to Game. What's the best way to do this?

FYI, I'm trying to create [Ultimate TTT](http://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2013/06/16/ultimate-tic-tac-toe/) in React.js.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you could do is pass a pointer to the Game function, as a property, to the Child component. For example:

```
var Game = React.createClass({
    gameFunction: function() {
        alert('gameFunction()');
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="game">
                <h1>Game</h1>
                <Table gameFunction={this.gameFunction} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Table = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="table">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td onClick={this.props.gameFunction}>Cell</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

That being said, I'm brand new to React, and am not sure if this is the *correct* way to accomplish this!

Comment: I'm new to React, too and I think you're right. What concerned me is that if you want to pass a function from Game to Cell, you have to pass it from Game to Table, from Table to TableRow and finally from TableRow to Cell. It seemed odd for me at first, but I guess it's just how React is designed.

Comment: Yes, this is correct -- threading the callbacks through in this fashion makes it explicit what callbacks your component might fire.